# how to enable footer being clickable and set listener on it?

Tags: android, listview, footer

This is activity

```
private View footer;
private Button btnmore;

linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_content);
    linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    LayoutInflater liInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    linear.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_particularcategoryallnewslist, null));
linear.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_particularcategoryallnewslistfv, null));
    footer = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_particularcategoryallnewslistfv, null);
btnmore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_more); 

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
            R.layout.main_particularcategoryallnewslist, from, to);
    lv.addFooterView(footer); <-- how to set footer being clickable?
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the footer, i have a button but i set listener on it also no respond, i think footer must enable to be click then only can button being click.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main_ParticularCategoryAllNews.this,
                    Main_ParticularNewsDetail.class);
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("newsid", newsid[arg2]);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnmore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isOnline() == true) {
                linear2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.5F, 0.5F);
                alpha.setDuration(15);
                alpha.setFillAfter(true);
                linear.startAnimation(alpha);
                btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                webservice.UpdateMoreCatNews(catnewsid);
                int secondsDelayed = 3;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Main_ParticularCategoryAllNews.this,
                                Main_AllLatestNews.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
            } else {
                toast = Toast
                        .makeText(
                                Main_ParticularCategoryAllNews.this,
                                "Your device is not connect to internet, fail to update news!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                        | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

how to set listener when footer being click?

Comment: footer appear below of last element in listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use these tips below:

1. make a relative layout as your root layout
2. place on it your footer layout and your ListView
3. add this attribute in your ListView:

   ```
   android:layout_above="@id/your_footer_layout_id"
   ```

See [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/listviewwithfooter/) link for more details. You can check a view is being clicked by the following `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.my_footer: 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "footer clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case R.id.my_header: 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "header clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your footer's xml add android:clickable="true"

Comment: and after that in your activity set a clicklistener on it

Comment: but how to check the footer is being clicked?

Comment: see updated answer, hope that snippet wil help you, implement the callback OnClickListener in your Activity

Answer (score 9):

The listview and button are fighting for focus and the listview is winning.

Set the following on the footer. `false` tells the footer it is not selectable:

```
 mylistView.addFooterView(footerView, null, **false**);
```

Or, you can use an `OnClickListener` as FireDevil suggests here.

Answer (score 8):

There is a way easier solution:

Just set a `OnClickListener` to the applied `View`:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, null);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Very easy thing which solved it!

Comment: I did this, but set the `onClickListener` to a button inside the view, with a call to the function that `jsemanue` mentioned.  Otherwise the `onItemClick` was firing instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the root of your footer view to use `<merge />` instead of `LinearLayout`. The parent of a `View` in a `ListView` must be of type `AbsListView`. Then, in code, you would inflate your footer `View` like this:

```
liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_particularcategoryallnewslistfv, lv, false);
```

**Edit**

The `<merge />` part may be unnecessary. Try just changing the inflation method first to the above.

Comment: second layout is using linear layout but it does not allow to use Linear layout

Comment: So inflate it using the method I posted. And what do you mean by 2nd layout?

Comment: second layout is the main_particularcategoryallnewslistfv xml

In this xml, i am using linear layout but then it cannot be add into listview because listview is using absolutelistview layout.